# How to Generate QR Code using C# ? how to show a PDF file when a generated QR code is scanned

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

Im bit of new to QR codes and i want know how to show a pdf file when a qr code is scanned ,without using 3rd party lib. can you please show me the right path help me with this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to publish your PDF File online to be accessible by a web browser. Then you'll need to generate a link to that file e.g. https://yourdomain.in/your-file.pdf

The QR Code is just a way to make this link readable by a camera. There is no way to create a QR Code without a 3rd party lib in .net. You could use QRCoder to generate a QRCode for your link like:

```
Url generator = new Url("https://yourdomain.in/your-file.pdf");
string payload = generator.ToString();

QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(payload, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
var qrCodeAsBitmap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
```